# Proving a function isn't 1 to 1

Tags: one-to-one, radix

I have a function called Base B, it calculates the base 2,3,4,5 etc of a number and outputs a number. I need to prove that this function is not 1 to 1. I am having difficulty of thinking how to derive an example.

Also have a recursive sequence that uses the formula: 2*f(x-1)-2*f(x-2)

I don't want just the answer, but how you choose your numbers and why you chose those.

Thanks!

```
public static long BaseB(long X,long X1){
    long Y = 0; //This also covers are base case because if x is 0 we will return 0
    long tmp;
    long powerOf10 = 1; //Will give a factor of *10 later

    while(X > 0){
        tmp = X % X1;
        Y = tmp * powerOf10 + Y;
        X /= X1;
        powerOf10 *= 10;
    }
   return Y;
}
```

This is the Recursive:

```
public static long RecursiveSeq(long x){
    if(x==1) return 1; //Base case 1
    else if(x==2) return 3; //Base case 2

//For all other case it will calculate here and create a stack
    else{
       return 2*RecursiveSeq(x-1)- 2*RecursiveSeq(x-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 1 to 1? Your `BaseB` function takes two arguments but only returns one result.

Comment: So every input can only be assigned to one value in the domain. Well yes it's meant to be that way because it's doing a calculation of bases.

Comment: OK, then it's obviously not injective because the set of possible inputs is much bigger than the set of possible results (N x N vs N).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. The function is already written and presumably works correctly.